# gcloud storage mkdocs and index.html don't play nice

Tags: gcloud, gsutil, mkdocs

I am hosting a static site on google cloud storage that is generated by `mkdocs`. The error that I am experiencing however, shouldn't be related by this library though.

I have my permissions set up and I can view the site over at

```
https://storage.googleapis.com/<bucketname>/<folder>/index.html
```

This is fine, but it cannot open this url:

```
https://storage.googleapis.com/<bucketname>/<folder>/
```

It doesn't recognise that it should grab the `index.html` file.

This isn't so much an issue for the index page (I could just point users to that page) but it is a huge issue for all the other links on the site. There's a subfolder that is generated with this structure:

```
site/planning
├── week1
│   └── index.html
├── week2
│   └── index.html
├── week3
│   └── index.html
└── week4
    └── index.html
```

The [google storage docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website) share some light on what might be going on. But even after applying their recommendation it doesn't work.

```
> gsutil web set -m index.html gs://<bucketname>/
Setting website configuration on gs://<bucketname>/...
```

So I'm looking for a solution. My thoughts are:

1. Maybe GCloud doesn't like the fact that I don't have my own domain name. This should matter but it might not help.
2. Maybe there's a setting in mkdocs such that not everything is generated via `index.html`.
3. Not use GCloud storage for this and instead use github/gitlab pages or something to host this static site.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the GCS part, this behaviour is explained in [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/static-website#tip-api):

> **Website configurations are only used to interpret requests directed to
>   CNAME aliases of c.storage.googleapis.com.** (that is, requests where
>   the hostname is a custom domain). For example, only requests to
>   www.example.com show the index page.
>
> Thus, API behavior for requests to Cloud Storage domains, such as
>   storage.googleapis.com/www.example.com, is preserved. For example, you
>   can continue to list objects in the www.example.com bucket as you
>   would for any other bucket. In the case of the www.example.com bucket,
>   the object listing you receive includes 404.html and index.html.

This mainly means that there are no redirects or special behaviors when accessing the objects through the API address, since this would cause the API to be inconsistent.

Definitely, the issue in GCS is that you're not using a custom domain.

On the mkdocs part, it looks like the [`use_directory_urls:false`](https://www.mkdocs.org/user-guide/configuration/#use_directory_urls) would do the trick.